# How to add elements fast but not instantly in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to fill an element with dots in random order. I have managed to write all the functionality, but I am not satisfied with the execution speed.

If I add all of the points using a while loop, the points just seem to appear all at the same time.

Therefore I add points one by one using a function that I call recursively with a timeout. This, on the other hand, appears too slow. Is there any chance to run a sequence of actions slower than in a loop but faster than `setTimeout()` can?

```js
var dotCellSize;
var initialOffset;
var slotsHorizontally;
var slotsVertically;
var container;
var redDots;
var dots;

var newDotElement = $('<div class="dot">');

function randomInteger(min,max)
{
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function addDots()
{
 if (!dots.length)
  return;
 
 var dotIndex = randomInteger(0, dots.length - 1);
 var dot = dots[dotIndex];
 
 dots.splice(dotIndex, 1);
 
 var column = dot % slotsHorizontally;
 var row = Math.floor(dot/slotsHorizontally);
 
 var position = {
  left: initialOffset + column*dotCellSize,
  top: initialOffset + row*dotCellSize
 };
 
 var dotElement = newDotElement.clone().css(position);
 
 if (-1 != redDots.indexOf(dot))
  dotElement.addClass('red');
 
 dotElement.appendTo(container);
  
 setTimeout(function() {
  addDots();
 }, 1);
}

function generateDots(dotContainer, cellSize, numberOfRedDots)
{
 container = dotContainer;
 dotCellSize = cellSize;
 dots = [];
 redDots = [];
 
 container.find('div.dot').remove();
 
 numberOfRedDots = typeof numberOfRedDots !== 'undefined' ? numberOfRedDots : 3;
 
 initialOffset = Math.floor(dotCellSize/2);

 slotsHorizontally = Math.ceil(container.width()/dotCellSize);
 slotsVertically = Math.ceil(container.height()/dotCellSize);

 var numberOfSlots = slotsHorizontally*slotsVertically;
 
 while (dots.length < numberOfSlots)
  dots.push(dots.length);

 while (redDots.length < numberOfRedDots)
 {
  var newRedDot = randomInteger(0, numberOfSlots - 1);
  
  if (-1 == redDots.indexOf(newRedDot))
   redDots.push(newRedDot);
 }
 
 addDots();
}

generateDots($('.dot-container'), 18, 15);
```

```css
.dot {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #C0E3EA;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dot.red {
  background-color: #EF3D48;
}

.dot-container {
  width: 420px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot-container"></div>
```

Comment: you dont have to use recursion, just synchronously call the setTimeouts with a randomized delay parameter.

Comment: thought it would probably be more performant to add all the dots with `opacity: 0` at once then use your randomizer logic to change their styling asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not really, this is because of how the browser engine decides to repaint the screen. Without the timeout, the browser engine recognizes it's going to do a bunch of updates (adding the dots to the DOM). Because repainting the screen is expensive, it waits to do as much as possible at one time, and, in your case, all of the dots show up at once. With the timeout added, each call to your function gets "deferred" for future execution.

This may or may not happen "right away" and is non-trivial to explain in detail so I would recommend watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ which explains the JS event loop or read some articles on browser reflow:

- [Minimizing browser reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow)
- [What is Layout Thrashing?](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/08/beware-javascript-layout-thrashing/)

Without changing much of what you've already done, one solution is to batch a few of the dots to be drawn together. I've added a `for` loop to your function which will make five dots get drawn together. Adjust this to 10, 20, or higher and you'll see the dots get painted even faster. I hope there is a number that you'll find suitable. I understand you may want to just speed up the drawing of every dot individually, but bear in mind that screens have refresh rates, so the faster you want the routine to finish the more they will appear in batches any way.

```js
var dotCellSize;
var initialOffset;
var slotsHorizontally;
var slotsVertically;
var container;
var redDots;
var dots;

var newDotElement = $('<div class="dot">');

function randomInteger(min,max)
{
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function addDots()
{
 if (!dots.length)
  return;
 
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var dotIndex = randomInteger(0, dots.length - 1);
    var dot = dots[dotIndex];

    dots.splice(dotIndex, 1);

    var column = dot % slotsHorizontally;
    var row = Math.floor(dot/slotsHorizontally);

    var position = {
      left: initialOffset + column*dotCellSize,
      top: initialOffset + row*dotCellSize
    };

    var dotElement = newDotElement.clone().css(position);

    if (-1 != redDots.indexOf(dot))
      dotElement.addClass('red');

    dotElement.appendTo(container);
  }
    setTimeout(function() {
      addDots();
    }, 1);
}

function generateDots(dotContainer, cellSize, numberOfRedDots)
{
 container = dotContainer;
 dotCellSize = cellSize;
 dots = [];
 redDots = [];
 
 container.find('div.dot').remove();
 
 numberOfRedDots = typeof numberOfRedDots !== 'undefined' ? numberOfRedDots : 3;
 
 initialOffset = Math.floor(dotCellSize/2);

 slotsHorizontally = Math.ceil(container.width()/dotCellSize);
 slotsVertically = Math.ceil(container.height()/dotCellSize);

 var numberOfSlots = slotsHorizontally*slotsVertically;
 
 while (dots.length < numberOfSlots)
  dots.push(dots.length);

 while (redDots.length < numberOfRedDots)
 {
  var newRedDot = randomInteger(0, numberOfSlots - 1);
  
  if (-1 == redDots.indexOf(newRedDot))
   redDots.push(newRedDot);
 }
 
 addDots();
}

generateDots($('.dot-container'), 18, 15);
```

```css
.dot {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #C0E3EA;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dot.red {
  background-color: #EF3D48;
}

.dot-container {
  width: 420px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights on "why"s. I ended up with your solution, making the batch size dynamically calculated so the animations lasts about the same regardless of number of dots.

Answer (score 2):

Quickly profiling on my i7 3770k revealed that newDotElement.clone().css(position) took about .1 seconds. If you are running at 30 FPS, your frame time is .03 seconds. So you can see that Jquery clone is somewhat of a bottleneck.

However, your initial approach of drawing all the dots at once is sound, if you flag their styles to be "hidden". Then, when all the dots are added to the DOM, but are not visible, retrieve a list of their nodes (forgive the vanilla JS):

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dot-container")[0].childNodes);
```

Now you can iterate over them and simply change their visibility style from "hidden" to "visible". As skyline3000 points out, the limit with setTimeout (or even requestAnimationFrame) is in the browser, and looping and setting one dot per iteration will take a little over 1 frame, which is actually a little slow. So you can write yourself a little abraction which per call will set a certain number of elements' visibility styles to "visible". By adjusting the quantity of dots you make visible per call, you will speed up or slow down the animation.

```
function showDots() {
    var list = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dot-container")[0].childNodes);

    function draw(q) {
        var e;
        for (var i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            if (list.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            e = list.shift();
            e.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }

    function callback() {            
        if (list.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        draw(4);
        setTimeout(callback);
    }

    callback();
}
```

Comment: Are you actually saying that cloning and styling a single element takes 0.1 second on your machine? Is there a noticably faster way to add elements?
 Should I just make a string of elements and then append it to document first? And then select again and restyle one by one?

Comment: Vanilla JS Node.cloneNode was about 10 times faster than JQuery's version on my machine: but! "This is not the bottleneck we're looking for..." Yes, I am suggesting creating and appending all the DOM nodes, and then later selecting and restyling "one by one" (or by two, or by four...depending on how slow / fast you want it).